# I am creating a calling app with Flutter and I want to hide the contact number and show only the name

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am creating a calling app with Flutter and I want to hide the contact number and show only the name

[image]

This is the code I used
**I want the phone number not to be shown during the call I just want the name to appear**

```
   IconButton(
                icon: DynamicTheme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                    ? Icon(GroovinMaterialIcons.comment_text_outline)
                    : Icon(GroovinMaterialIcons.comment_text),
                onPressed: () {
                  //  globals.callToEdit = widget.callSnapshot.reference;
                  launch("sms:${widget.callSnapshot.phone}");
                },
                tooltip: "Text ${widget.callSnapshot.firstName}",
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: DynamicTheme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                    ? Icon(GroovinMaterialIcons.phone_outline)
                    : Icon(Icons.phone),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await CallNumber().callNumber("${widget.callSnapshot.phone}");
                },
                tooltip: "Call ${widget.callSnapshot.phone}",
              ),
```

```
class CallNumber {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('sreenathsdas/call_number');

  //static Future<String> get callNumber =>
    //  _channel.invokeMethod('callNumber');

  Future<String> callNumber(String number) async {
    if (number == null) {
        return "NULL";
    }
    return await _channel.invokeMethod(
        'callNumber',
        <String, Object>{'number': number},
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a boolean operator say:

```
is_calling = false
```

and set it to true when the calling happens and render widgets based on that condition